# Kentico CMS: Text area input length calculation and determining max length - specifically when there are line breaks in the text

Tags: forms, validation, content-management-system, textarea, kentico

**How does Kentico calculate the length of inputted content in a text area on a form and how much value does it give to a line break?** A line break is 2 characters according to my JavaScript calculation but seems like Kentico calculates it as being more than 2 characters.

**Summary of problem:**

I have a maximum length of 2500 set on a text area input on a form on my Kentico site.

I have entered some text into a this text area and with my JavaScript calculations (used to show how many characters the user has left) the character length is exactly 2500 (including line breaks and spaces) and so should therefore validate and send. However Kentico is failing my input saying that my max length has been exceeded. See below:

[image]

If I remove the line break and type some extra characters to bring my character calculation back up to 2500, the form sends without failing.

**Test used that fails:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae
>   augue ac enim molestie scelerisque a id metus. Suspendisse purus
>   justo, iaculis quis accumsan ut, congue vitae mauris. Nunc luctus
>   vulputate scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta elit, sed ornare lorem
>   placerat dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae
>   felis. Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin
>   sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus lectus.
>   Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae felis. Sed
>   porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin sapien, at
>   scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus lectus. Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae augue ac
>   enim molestie scelerisque a id metus. Suspendisse purus justo, iaculis
>   quis accumsan ut, congue vitae mauris. Nunc luctus vulputate
>   scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta elit, sed ornare lorem placerat
>   dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae felis.
>   Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin
>   sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus
>   lectus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>   Quisque vitae augue ac enim molestie scelerisque a id metus.
>   Suspendisse purus jus
>
> to, iaculis quis accumsan ut, congue vitae mauris. Nunc luctus
>   vulputate scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta elit, sed ornare lorem
>   placerat dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae
>   felis. Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin
>   sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus lectus.
>   Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae felis. Sed
>   porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin sapien, at
>   scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus lectus. Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae augue ac
>   enim molestie scelerisque a id metus. Suspendisse purus justo, iaculis
>   quis accumsan ut, congue vitae mauris. Nunc luctus vulputate
>   scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta elit, sed ornare lorem placerat
>   dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae felis.
>   Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin
>   sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus
>   lectus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>   Quisque vitae augue ac enim molestie scelerisque a id metus.
>   Suspendisse purus justo, iaculis quis accumsan ut, congue vitae maur d

**Test used that passes:** Notice that the line break has been removed and 2 extra characters added to the end to bring it back up to 2500 characters

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae
>   augue ac enim molestie scelerisque a id metus. Suspendisse purus
>   justo, iaculis quis accumsan ut, congue vitae mauris. Nunc luctus
>   vulputate scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta elit, sed ornare lorem
>   placerat dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae
>   felis. Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin
>   sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus lectus.
>   Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae felis. Sed
>   porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin sapien, at
>   scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus lectus. Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae augue ac
>   enim molestie scelerisque a id metus. Suspendisse purus justo, iaculis
>   quis accumsan ut, congue vitae mauris. Nunc luctus vulputate
>   scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta elit, sed ornare lorem placerat
>   dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis sagittis nec vitae felis.
>   Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere, neque dui sollicitudin
>   sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis enim. Donec at metus
>   lectus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>   Quisque vitae augue ac enim molestie scelerisque a id metus.
>   Suspendisse purus justo, iaculis quis accumsan ut, congue vitae
>   mauris. Nunc luctus vulputate scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta
>   elit, sed ornare lorem placerat dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh
>   convallis sagittis nec vitae felis. Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat
>   posuere, neque dui sollicitudin sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis
>   enim. Donec at metus lectus. Sed quis enim quis nibh convallis
>   sagittis nec vitae felis. Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat posuere,
>   neque dui sollicitudin sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis enim.
>   Donec at metus lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae augue ac enim molestie scelerisque a id
>   metus. Suspendisse purus justo, iaculis quis accumsan ut, congue vitae
>   mauris. Nunc luctus vulputate scelerisque. Nullam ullamcorper porta
>   elit, sed ornare lorem placerat dictum. Sed quis enim quis nibh
>   convallis sagittis nec vitae felis. Sed porttitor, nibh et volutpat
>   posuere, neque dui sollicitudin sapien, at scelerisque lacus elit quis
>   enim. Donec at metus lectus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae augue ac enim molestie scelerisque a id
>   metus. Suspendisse purus justo, iaculis quis accumsan ut, congue vitae
>   maur dee

Comment: I tried one with the copied text, and a maximum length of 2500 and it works. It appears the CMSTextbox is doing nothing more than checking the text.Length property against the maximum length. You sure there isn't something else going on? Is your line break a single line break, or a double line break? If it's two, it will come back as 2502 characters.

Comment: yes I think the error lay in my length calculation for a line break not matching up to the length that Kentico gives to a line break. My calculation `textareaElement.val().length` gives a line break a length of 1, while Kentico's calculation gives a value of 2 to a line break. I have reviewed how I calculate the length of the input so that each line break adds on an extra 1 to the total character count. I'll post my calculation up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay in the fact that my calculation in my JavaScript gave a length of 1 to a line break whereby Kentico's calculation gives a length of 2 to a line break. So they weren't matching up. Hence my character counter said that the length of the entered text was ok but Kentico's check deemed it over the max length.

**This is what I had previously:**

```
enteredText = textareaVariableName.val();
characterCount = enteredText.length; //one line break entered returned 1
```

**This is what I have changed it to:**

```
enteredText = textareaVariableName.val();
enteredTextEncoded = escape(enteredText);
//next I match any line break characters - %0A - after encoding the text area text
linebreaks = enteredTextEncoded.match(/%0A/g);
(linebreaks != null) ? linebreaksLength = linebreaks.length : linebreaksLength = 0;
characterCount = enteredText.length + linebreaksLength; //one line break entered now returns 2
```

**Is there a better way I could check for line breaks in the text, rather than to encode the text and then check for the substring %0A ?**

**EDIT/UPDATE:** I believe the following is a better solution as opposed to what I was doing above.

```
var limit = 2500; //for example
enteredText = textareaVariableName.val();
numberOfLineBreaks = (enteredText.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
left = limit - enteredText.length - numberOfLineBreaks;
if (left < 0) {
    //character count over code here
} else {
    //character count within limits code here               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically JavaScript problem related to browser. In Firefox or Chrome or any other WebKit based browser textareaVariableName.val().length will count only 1 character for new line (\n). Same for jQuery implementation. But in IE document.getElementById('textareaVariableName').value.length will count 2 for new line (\r\n)

In Kentico, the text is validated to the actual count of characters and therefore the validation is failing.

Quick fix for this is simple regular expression for counting the actual length:

```
function getTextLength(elementId){
   if (elementId) {
      var elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
      if (elem) {
         var str = elem.value;
         if (str) {
            str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\r\n');
            return str.length;
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This should help you to count characters correctly independently of the browser used by the customer.